# Differentiablity of $h(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $ x\neq 0$ and $h(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

$h(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})& x\neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow f:\mathbb{R}^+, x\mapsto \exp(-x) $ and $g:\mathbb{R}/\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}, x\mapsto \frac{1}{x^2} $.

For $x\neq 0$ $h(x)$ is differentiable because of the chain rule, which can be applied since both $f,g$ are differentiable for $x\neq 0$ and $g(\mathbb{R}/\{0\})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

I now want to proof that $h(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

I know that the function $g$ is not continuous at $x=0$: $\underset{x\neq 0}{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}}g(x)=\infty$.

For every $x\neq 0$ both $f,g$ are continuous, so that:
$$\underset{x\neq 0}{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}}h(x)=\exp(-\underset{x\neq 0}{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}}\frac{1}{x^2})\rightarrow 0=h(0)$$ because $\underset{x\neq 0}{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}}\frac{1}{x^2}\rightarrow \infty$.

So $h(x)$ is a continuous function at $x=0$.

Now let's look at the differential quotient at $x=0$:

$$\underset{x\neq 0}{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}=\underset{x\neq 0}{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}}\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}=\underset{x\neq 0}{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}}\frac{1}{x\exp(\frac{1}{x^2})}=?$$

Can somebody help me?

Maybe this transformation is useful: $x\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\frac{1}{x^2})^k}{k!}=x(1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2x^4}-\frac{1}{6x^6}\pm...)=x-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^3}-\frac{1}{6x^5}\pm... $

Comment: $e^x$ is "stronger" than any polynomial  thus $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}= + \infty$ . This is an elementary result.

Comment: $\exp(y)>y$ when $y\geq 0,$ so $|x\exp(1/x^2)|> |x|\cdot 1/x^2=1/|x|\to\infty$ as $x\to 0.$

Comment: You don't have to put $x\neq 0$ in your $\lim_{x\to 0}.$ The limit always is talking about values other than $x=0,$ by definition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [Depends.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Deleted_versus_non-deleted_limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the inequality $\exp(y)>y$ for all $y.$ This follows from the power series for $\exp(y)$ for $y\geq 0$ and is true when $y<0$ trivially since $\exp(y)>0>y.$

Then for $x\neq 0,$ $$\left|x\exp(1/x^2)\right|>|x|\cdot 1/x^2=1/|x|.$$

So $$\left|\frac{1}{x\exp(1/x^2)}\right|<|x|.$$ So as $x\to 0,$ $\frac{1}{x\exp(1/x^2)}\to 0.$

---

In fact, you can use more generally, for any integer $n\geq 0,$ that $\exp(y)>y^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ for all $y\geq 0$ to show that:

$$\left|x^n\exp(1/x^2)\right|>|x|^n\frac{1}{x^{2(n+1)}(n+1)!}= \frac{1}{(n+1)!|x|^{n+2}},$$ so $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^n\exp(1/x^2)}= 0$$ for any integer $n\geq 0.$

Answer (score 2):

How about L'hopital? $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac {1/x}{e^{1/x^2}}\overset {\text {L'h}}{=}\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac {-1/x^2\cdot x^3}{-2e^{1/x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac {x}{2e^{1/x^2}}=0$$.